# Symbol server authentication failed for C# application in VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017, debug-symbols

I'm working on some DLLs, based on a C# application. I'm working with Visual Studio 2017, version 15.9.49.
I was logged in in my Visual Studio environment, using a Hotmail account.

This morning, I received a mail on my work e-mail address, saying that "One of your personal access tokens will be expiring on 7/7/2022.". When I clicked on that, I did some approval, using the authenticator app on my work smartphone, and I was told everything is ok.

However, I got an error message from my Visual Studio environment and I switched to my work e-mail related VS account.

However, when I try to launch my executable, I get the following error message:

> 'application.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: application.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Tools\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'. Symbol server authentication failed.
> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException' in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
> Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
> The program '[39464] application.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The program '[39464] application.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

For your information: I'm not sure about the version of the mentioned executable.

Can anybody shed some light here: is the error message based on some "account" where something is wrong, or is something wrong with the version of my application.exe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. Re-entering your Visual Studio credentials and restarting VS helped in my case.